# Containing type does not implement interface IMessageFilter

Tags: c#

I'm still trying to find out what is happening with this error:

> *OCR.test.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message): containing type does not implement interface System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter*

Here are my codes:

```
bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) // Error with this line
{
    TwainCommand cmd = tw.PassMessage(ref m);
    if (cmd == TwainCommand.Not)
        return false;

    switch (cmd)
    {
        case TwainCommand.CloseRequest:
        {
            EndingScan();
            tw.CloseSrc();
            break;
        }
        case TwainCommand.CloseOk:
        {
            EndingScan();
            tw.CloseSrc();
            break;
        }
        case TwainCommand.DeviceEvent:
        {
           break;
        }
        case TwainCommand.TransferReady:
        {
            ArrayList pics = tw.TransferPictures();
            EndingScan();
            tw.CloseSrc();
            picnumber++;
            for (int i = 0; i < pics.Count; i++)
            {
                IntPtr img = (IntPtr)pics[i];
                PicForm newpic = new PicForm(img);
                newpic.MdiParent = this;
                int picnum = i + 1;
                //newpic.Text = "ScanPass " + picnumber.ToString() + "_Pic " + picnum.ToString();
                newpic.Show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think one of your classes needs to implement the IMessageFilter interface.

Comment: How can I implement? Can you show me some examples?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial in order to learn how to implement an interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx. You will want to implement the `IMessageFilter` interface on whatever type is required in your method. Are `Message` and `TwainMessage` classes you have defined?

Answer (score 2):

The class where you implement the PreFilterMessage method needs to derive from IMessageFilter Interface. You probably missed it

```
public class Foo: IMessageFilter
{
   bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
   {
       // your code
   }
}
```

Comment: Here is the full error message:
    Error 2 'OCR.test.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)': containing type does not implement interface 'System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter' C:\Users\Faesal\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\OCR\OCR\test.cs 53 14 OCR

Comment: @MrKrahoz - Re-read Srodriguez answer.  You have a class called test that does not implement the IMessageFilter interface.  You need to change your test class to something like this:  `public class test : IMessageFilter`